# Call to javascript function stop working when adding parameter, is this really not aloud?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters

When I remove my anonymous function, and call a function directly it only works if it's without the parameter.

**Works.** With parameter, inside an anonymous function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#someId').on('click', function () {
        setAllOn(checkOn)
    });
});
function setAllOn(checkOn) {
    $("#someId2 input[name='someName']").attr('checked', checkOn);
}
```

**Works**. Without an anonymous function, but only without parameters:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#someId').on('click', setAllOn);
});
function setAllOn() {
    $("#someId2 input[name='someName']").attr('checked', true);
}
```

**Don't work**. A parameter is added, and now it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#someId').on('click', setAllOn(true));
});
function setAllOn(checkOn) {
    $("#someId2 input[name='someName']").attr('checked', checkOn);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a callback to `on` i.e. a function to be called when the event is fired.

`setAllOn` is a function. That's why it works.

`function () {
        setAllOn(checkOn)
    }` still a function.

`setAllOn(true)` is the result of calling function `setAllOn`. Since it returns nothing the result is `undefined`. Which is not a function.

If you want to re-use `setAllOn` function. You can define a higher order function, taking argument and returning a "curried" version of `setAllOn`.

```
function setAll(checkOn){
    return function(){ return setAllOn(checkOn);}
}

function setAllOn(checkOn) {
    $("#someId2 input[name='someName']").attr('checked', checkOn);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#someId').on('click', setAll(true));
});
```

Comment: or `function setAllOn(checkOn){ /* blah */ return arguments.callee;}`

Comment: Oh so it fail because I didn't return anything(callback). That's not intuitive for a beginner. "If you add a parameter, the function have to return something I never use.

Comment: "setAllOn(true) is the result of calling function setAllOn", this part I don't get. How can the function turn into a result, just by adding a parameter.

Comment: It's not caused by the parameter. try replace `setAllOn` with `setAllOn()` in your 2nd code, it will failed too.

Comment: You are not "adding a parameter" you are actually calling a function.

Comment: Consider the following example: `function increment(a){return a+1;}; console.log(typeof increment); console.log(typeof increment(1));` `incremenent` is a function. `increment(1)` is a number.

Comment: Please see my second sample again. If I calling my function where the function don't have parameter, it works. If the function have a parameter it dosn't. But okay maybe you allready answered this. Maybe i just have to get use to thinking in these lines. Thank you for the answer. I learned alot and will stick with my sample 1.

Comment: `setAllOn` without '()' is just a reference to something called `setAllOn` which happens to be a function. By adding '()' you are saying to js engine to do the following steps '1. Find something named setAllOn. 2. Consider it to be a function and invoke it.' Since the result of evaluating `setAllOn()` is `undefined` it can't be used as an event handler.

Comment: Ah okay! It makes alot of sense now, you helped me alot.